# IE Browser Not working when we minimize it

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, selenium-grid, iedriverserver

All I am Testing the web automation script using IE Mode in the edge browser I am using 4.8.1 IE driver 32-bit, and selenium 4.0.1 works very well for me but when I minimize the screen or lock the screen it will stick to initialize browser page only

public class AlertPopUp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\AlertPopUp\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    RemoteWebDriver driver = null;

    try {
    
        InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        

        
        ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
        ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
        ieOptions.requireWindowFocus();
        ieOptions.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
        ieOptions.ignoreZoomSettings();
        ieOptions.destructivelyEnsureCleanSession();
        ieOptions.setCapability (InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false) ;
        ieOptions.setCapability ("disable-popup-blocking", true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        
        
        driver.quit();
        
        
        
        
        
    

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}
Exception:-
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
4.8.1.0
Listening on port 29726
Only local connections are allowed
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'AJAX', ip: '192.168.0.106'
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.4.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, disable-popup-blocking: true, se:ieOptions: {enablePersistentHover: false, ie.edgechromium: true, ie.edgepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true, ignoreZoomSetting: true, requireWindowFocus: true}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, disable-popup-blocking: true, se:ieOptions: {enablePersistentHover: false, ie.edgechromium: true, ie.edgepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true, ignoreZoomSetting: true, requireWindowFocus: true}}}]
Capabilities {}
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:153)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:140)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:117)
at testpopup.AlertPopUp.main(AlertPopUp.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: NettyHttpHandler request execution error
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:76)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:124)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:29726 after 180000 ms
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2096)
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:59)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:29726 after 180000 ms
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.TimeoutTimerTask.expire(TimeoutTimerTask.java:43)
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.RequestTimeoutTimerTask.run(RequestTimeoutTimerTask.java:50)
at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:715)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.ImmediateExecutor.execute(ImmediateExecutor.java:34)
at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:703)
at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:790)
at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:503)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems a known issue of IEDriver. You can refer to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver/issues/15). The Edge team is aware of the issue but hasn't provide a fix for it. The suggestion from the official member in the last comment is below:

> I'd recommend working around this by running any tests that require IE on a dedicated machine or VM that can remain logged in interactively.